# Google Cloud Run - custom Cloud Logging attributes

Tags: node.js, express, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

Is there a way to add custom attributes to the automatically generated logs for Cloud Run services?

```js
const app = express();
app.use((req: any, res, next) => {
  const myCustomHeader = req.get('x-my-custom-header');
  // TODO: Add my custom header to Cloud Run automatic logs
  next();
});
```

I would like to add `myCustomHeader` to the Cloud Logging output (e.g. to its `httpRequest` object):

```js
{
 httpRequest: {
   myCustomHeader: "my custom value here",
   … // Default attributes set by Cloud Run
 },
 insertId:  "5c82b3d1000ece0000000000",
 labels: {
  instanceId:  "someid",
  mylabel: "mylabelvalue",
  mysecondlabel: "mysecondlabelvalue",
 },
 logName:  "projects/my-project/logs/run.googleapis.com%2Frequests",
 receiveTimestamp:  "2019-03-08T18:26:25.981686167Z",
 resource: {
  labels: {
   configuration_name:  "myservice",
   location:  "us-central1",
   project_id:  "my-project",
   revision_name:  "myservice-00002",
   service_name:  "myservice",
  }
  type:  "cloud_run_revision",
 },
 severity:  "INFO",
 timestamp:  "2019-03-08T18:26:25.970397Z",
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per this **[official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/logging#container-logs)**

> When you write logs from your service or job, they will be picked up automatically by Cloud Logging so long as the logs are written to any of these locations:
>
> - Standard output (stdout) or standard error (stderr) streams
> - Any files under the /var/log directory
> - syslog (/dev/log)
> - Logs written using Cloud Logging client libraries, which are available for many popular languages
>
> Most developers are expected to write logs using standard output and standard error.

So if you want to add some custom attributes to the logs follow the steps given in the documentation for generating logs.

Comment: I read this, yet (correct me if I'm wrong), I do not see any information/examples of adding extra attributes to the automatically generated log for each incoming requests (e.g. using a middleware or so) – hence the question here.

Comment: @mdmb The log which you have provided are platform logs, [Google Cloud platform logs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/api/platform-logs) are service-specific logs that can help you debug and troubleshoot issues, as well as better understand the Google Cloud services you're using. ***After refering these docs I found there is no way to edit platform logs,*** will let you know if I find anything thanks

Comment: Thank you! I've been trying different approaches, but without any luck.

Comment: @mdmb As of now there is no way for adding custom attributes to platform logs. So, if you want to collect the http header of the requester you can use `request.getHeader()` method as mentioned in this [doc](https://www.educative.io/answers/what-is-requestgetheader-in-node) and write the logs to cloud logging as mentioned above. Go through this and let us know if you are still having some queries.